# How to find out the reason of slowdown UI in my application?

Tags: android

Is that possible to find out the reason which caused lagging of UI like specific thread or method?

Cause I kind of put all the heavy work into another thread but I've still getting a lagged UI.

I'm using `CameraX` where `ImageAnalysis` works in separate thread in which I do emotion detection via neural network.
So when a neural network process an image in this not UI thread my UI thread also lags.

Is that possible at all? 
Can the separate thread slow down the UI thread by executing heavy task?

Maybe there's some plugin for Android Studio or something like that to solve the problem.

I will be glad to any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea to use the debugger with a lot of breakpoints. That way you know exactly where it starts to go int App Not Responsive behaviour.

Comment: I'll try that way

Comment: I know the heavy instruction (when neural net forwards image), but the most important question is why UI lags when neural network runs in separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do such heavy tasks with RxJava2! If you're not familiar with this library, [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-rxjava-in-android-e52ed7ef32e2) is very good for you to start!

Comment: seems you've attached an invalid link